# Parsing a sentence using logical operators (Logical expressions)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Parse the logical structure

"If everyone passes the quiz, Mr. Johnson will play his guitar."

-Use *q* as a constant to represent the quiz

-Use *g* as a constant to represent Mr. Johnson's guitar

-Use *u* as constant to represent Mr. Johnson

-Use $P(w, x)$ as the two-place predicate "w passes x"

-Use $Q(y, z)$ as the two-place predicate "y will play z"

Not sure if I am parsing this correctly
This what I have so far, but I feel that I am doing it wrong.

$\forall w(P(w,q))\rightarrow Q(u,g)$

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to start this. I understand how logical operators work but don't know how I would parse the sentence into a logical expression.

Start by replacing the constants and predicates for words.  PS: I also suggest use $v$ for "his guitar".

Next, apply the universal quantifier and express "If ... , (then) ..." as a logical connective.

---

(edit)

> Not sure if I am parsing this correctly. This what I have so far, but I feel that I am doing it wrong.
>
> $\forall w~(P(w,q))~\to~ Q(u,g)$

That is correct.

Comment: This is what I got but I feel its not correct: $\forall w(P(w,q))\rightarrow Q(u,g)$